# How create polymorphic agnostic models?

Tags: php, design-patterns, symfony, doctrine

Currently I use the storage agnostic pattern in my project. This pattern is pretty simple: I've my `Model\Model` and my specific storage layer that extends of `Model\Model` (like `Entity\Model` and `Document\Model`).

The problem I'm facing is with polymorphic objects. If I don't extend an entity Doctrine does not recognize the inheritance mapping. In that way I need to replicate my code for every storage layer:

```
class Model\Option {}
class Model\OptionNumber extends Option {}
class Entity\Model extends Model\Option {}
```

I would like to have:

```
class Entity\OptionNumber extends Model\OptionNumber{}
```

But it's not possible. I've to code in Entity\OptionNumber once PHP have no support for multiple inheritance.

Is there any pattern that solve this problem?

Just for reference, I'm using Doctrine 2.2 and Symfony 2.3.

Sure!

Model:

```
abstract class Option implements OptionInterface
{
/**
 * @var int
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @var string
 */
   protected $presentation;

   /**
   * @var Collection of OptionChoiceInterface
   */
   protected $choices;
}
```

Entity:

```
class Option extends BaseOption
{
}
```

Document:

```
class Option extends BaseOption
{
}
```

Comment: Can you show one model and one entity or document?

Comment: I've added the real examples.

Comment: [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/) does something close to what you want to do. They use their Models to keep their Objects storage independent (so you can use Doctrine or Doctrine Mongo). They do not really exercise polymorphic behavior however. I don't think you'll find a good way to accomplish this. You have to be coupled to Doctrine. Take a look at this doc, it may help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html